# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I Have an Error

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions
> When I call this method:

```
    public class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly TourDBContext context;

        public BaseRepository()
        {
            this.context = new TourDBContext();
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var list = await context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
                return list;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
     }

    public class CategoryRepository : BaseRepository<Category>
    {
    }
```

Here is my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TourDBContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TourDBConnectionString")));


builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TourDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<TourRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITourService, TourService>();
```

Here is my Context:

```
public class TourDBContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        SeedRoles(builder);

        // Bỏ tiền tố AspNet của các bảng
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
            if (tableName.StartsWith("AspNet"))
            {
                entityType.SetTableName(tableName.Substring(6));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SeedRoles(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var seedRoles = new List<IdentityRole>{
            new IdentityRole{ Name = "Admin", ConcurrencyStamp = "1", NormalizedName = "Admin"},
            new IdentityRole{ Name = "User", ConcurrencyStamp = "2", NormalizedName = "User"},
            new IdentityRole{ Name = "HR", ConcurrencyStamp = "3", NormalizedName = "HumanResources"}
        };

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(seedRoles);
    }
    public TourDBContext()
    {
    }
    public TourDBContext(DbContextOptions<TourDBContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

But when I write this in Context, the error does not occur. Will my writing OnConfiguring in DBContext and AddDbContext in Program.cs have any effect?

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(GetConnectionString());
                optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            }
        }

        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .Build();

            var strConn = config["ConnectionStrings:TravelDBConnectionString"];
            return strConn;
        }
```

Comment: You define the DbContext options within your DI container configuration ... but you manually create an instance of that DbContext within the repository. How should the manual creation of the DbContext know about the DI container configuration? **Solution**: Follow the DI path and your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

modify your repository to:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly TourDBContext _context;

        public BaseRepository(TourDBContext context)
        {
            _context =  context;
        }

       ......
     }
```